# Posição do geom_text ao utilizar o ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Tenho uma grande quantidade de gráficos utilizando o ggplot2. Ao utilizar o `ggplotly`, meu `geom_text` não obedece a posição do `ggplot()`. Veja gráfico abaixo:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df.csv"
teste <- fread(url)

plot <- ggplot(teste,
               aes(reorder(factor(UF), desc(Valor)),
                   y = Valor,
                   fill = UF,
                   text = paste("UF: ",UF,
                                "<br>",
                                "Valor: ",paste0("R$",formatC(1000000000*Valor, digits = 2, big.mark=',', format = 'f'))))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Valor),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -0.5,
            size = 3) +
  xlab("Unidade Federativa") +
  ylab("Valor Recebido") +
  theme_light() 
plotly::ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")%>%
  plotly::layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei várias soluções, uma delas foi utilizar a função `style` do `plotly` com a opção `textposition=’top’`. No entanto, meu `tooltip` aparece sobre as barras do gráfico e não consigo resolver isso.

```
plotly::ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")%>%
  plotly::style(textposition = "top") %>% 
  plotly::layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A opção `textposition` afeta o `geom_text` e também o `tooltip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removi os dados de `y` do `ggplot` e inclui via `plotly`.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df.csv"
teste <- fread(url)

plot <- ggplot(teste,
               aes(reorder(factor(UF), desc(Valor)),
                   y = Valor,
                   fill = UF,
                   text = paste("UF: ",UF,
                                "<br>",
                                "Valor: ",paste0("R$",formatC(1000000000*Valor, digits = 2, big.mark=',', format = 'f')))) ) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab("Unidade Federativa") +
  ylab("Valor Recebido") +
  theme_light() 

plotly::ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")%>%
  plotly::layout(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  plotly::style(texttemplate = '%{y:.2}', textposition = "outside")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]